# How to copy or borrow a reference to, an owned String inside an owned Vec?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to first set a `String` to be some default, but then update that `String` if a command line argument has been given...

This is my starting point (which doesn't compile):

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let mut config_file = "C:\\temp\\rust\\config.txt".to_string();
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() > 1 {
        config_file = args[1];
    }
    println!("Config file path: {}", config_file);
}
```

So, (I think) `env::args()` is giving me an owned vector or owned strings... How do I either:

- Copy a string in the vector
- Get a reference to a string in the vector

Note:

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.8.0 (db2939409 2016-04-11)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Rust, to create a copy of an element, it should implement the `Clone` trait, and thus have a `.clone()` method.

`String` implements `Clone`, thus:

```
config_file = args[1].clone();
```

---

Your method, however, has many unnecessary memory allocations; we can do better there is no need to create a `Vec`, `args()` yields an iterator so let's use that directly and cherry-pick the interesting value.

With this in mind:

```
fn main() {
    let mut config_file = "C:\\temp\\rust\\config.txt".to_string();

    if let Some(v) = env::args().nth(1) {
        config_file = v;
    }

    println!("Config file path: {}", config_file);
}
```

---

At the behest of Shepmaster: it's show time!

The following is an equivalent program, without mutability or escape characters, and with as little allocations as possible:

```
fn main() {
    let config_file = env::args()
        .nth(1)
        .unwrap_or_else(|| r#"C:\temp\rust\config.txt"#.to_string());

    println!("Config file path: {}", config_file);
}
```

It uses `unwrap_or_else` on the `Option` returned by `nth(1)` to get either the content of the `Option` or, if none, generate a value using the passed lambda.

It also show cases the [Raw String Literals](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#raw-string-literals), a great feature to use when having to embed back slashes in a string.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for answering the question *and* offering further improvement :thumbsup:

Comment: All that unneeded mutability, allocation, and escape characters! [You can slim it down a bit](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0102bc8d36aa19aeb38eb7c7e190d5db). ^_^